# How can i add items to the playlist without loading the website again via JavaScript after the Website has be reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

Im using howlerjs to create playlist on my page like in this example: https://howlerjs.com/#radio

Here is the js for the created example:

```
var radio = new Radio([
  {
    freq: '81.4',
    title: "BBC Radio 1",
    src: 'http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_q',
    howl: null
  },
  {
    freq: '89.9',
    title: "Hip Hop Hits",
    src: 'http://tunein4.streamguys1.com/hhbeafree5',
    howl: null
  },
  {
    freq: '98.9',
    title: "CNN",
    src: 'http://tunein.streamguys1.com/cnn',
    howl: null
  },
  {
    freq: '103.3',
    title: "80's Hits",
    src: 'http://tunein4.streamguys1.com/80shtfree1',
    howl: null
  },
  {
    freq: '107.7',
    title: "Today's Hits",
    src: 'http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/MusicPulse.mp3',
    howl: null
  }
]);
```

I want to create a button on the page that allows the user to add more stations on the page.

Comment: What you've tried so far to add more stations in the list?

Comment: Just add a button to the page, attach a click listener to it, and write some code to append the data to the above posted object and reinitialize it.

Comment: It's trivial to add a station to the list, just `push()` a new object to the array. However you need to then change the logic in the [radio example JS](https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/radio/radio.js) to then update the UI when the station has been added. I'd suggest making an attempt at this yourself then asking a question when you encounter an issue.

Comment: thanks to both of you your help. Will try both answers and then post a question again if i encounter issues

Answer (score 0):

create a button for adding playlist items and update the playlist on click event using jquery ajax.. more info: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (as i see jquery in tags)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I'm building a Vue Js project.
My goal was while the song is playing if I navigate to an artist album and click on a song
it should update the playlist but what I  noted is that howl was kinda creating another instance and end up playing 2 songs at the time. But I noticed that the instance created first was only accessible by the player component and whenever  I call any method of playermixin from another component apart of the playerMixin  it would not work (will give u an error of undefined howl)

THERE NO WAY YOU TO UPDATE THE PLAYLIST EASILY

MY_SOLUTION:
Since it did not have any problem with the player component 
I made Howl take the playlist from the store and had an index.
When the music starts playing it updates the index then created a function to update
the playlist in s=the store.

now to order howl to play music outside the player component I created an event when it's fired should stop the current song and starts a new one (at this point the playlist is already updated).

I hope this helps you figure out what to do in your case.

Comment: I know this question is a few years old, but any chance you still have the code you wrote for this? I've been banging my head against this problem for weeks now and you've described my exact issue. I've tried so many things with `Howler.unload()` but no luck so far.